# Why heap is getting full very fast with this code?

Tags: scala, memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm, large-files

The memory is getting full(with 30gb size) in 5 minutes. With this code, I just want to read the text file(3gb) entries into a map, but when I run this code, 10gb eden space is getting full in 3 seconds and after 5 minutes, old heap space is also getting full. What could be the reason? Here is the code:

```
object PairWordsReader extends App {

  val wordsAndCounts: Map[WordTuple, Int] =
    io.Source.fromFile("/home/katilsperm/pairWords.txt").getLines.map {
      string =>
        val Array(w1,w2,freq) = string.split(",")
        WordTuple(w1,w2) -> freq.toInt
    }.toMap
}
```

Custom tuple class:

```
case class WordTuple(x: String, y: String) {
  override def equals(that: scala.Any): Boolean = that match {
    case that: WordTuple => ( that canEqual this ) && (
      (this.x == that.x && this.y == that.y) ||
        (this.x == that.y && this.y == that.x)
      )
    case _ => false
  }
  override def canEqual( that:Any ): Boolean = that.isInstanceOf[WordTuple]
  override def hashCode: Int = x.hashCode + y.hashCode
  override def toString: String = x + "," + y
}
```

Here, visualvm screenshots to explain problem more clearly:
[image: Overview]

[image: System Monitor]

[image: Garbage Collector]

[image: Memory Usage]

The memory is just going crazy. Why don't temporary char array and String objects are just cleaned up by gc and only HashMap entries occupy the memory. What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks.

**BTW, the actual problem is:**
I have 3 pieces of 3gb text files which contains co-occurred word tuples and their frequencies in this format:
human,brain,1919
car,oil,1920
people,victory,1923
etc.
And I need the merge these files into a file. While merging, frequency of same word tuples must be summed.

Comment: because you are using those "temporary" String objects to as arguments to your WordTuple... which you are storing in your Map. They are not actually temporary.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh but still, how could it be possible that String and char Array objects occupy this much memory? The text file is only 3gb size

Comment: A String in Java is (2 Bytes per character) + (16 Byte object overhead) + 12 (Bytes array overhead)... which means `(28 + 2*n) Bytes` for a String of `n` characters. So, even your small strings of size 5 which were just 10 Bytes in your file will be 38 Bytes in JVM.

Comment: The above estimate is not actually very accurate. As there may be other overheads involved depending on your Java version and JVM architecture.

Comment: The only things which matter is the amount retained after a full GC. Can you trigger a `Perform GC` to see how much is actually retained? It says "old gen: 0 collections" which means you have no idea how much is really being retained.

Answer (score 0):

The GC is only performed which you need it to. The default collector only runs when all the space is used, any sooner would most likely have higher overhead.

In your chart it indicates your old gen collector has never run so rather than being full (which you can only tell after a collection) it might be almost empty after a collection.

BTW A single word could easily use 8 objects for the data structure you have or about 256 bytes memory each. If you have half a billion words, that's about 128 GB of memory you need.  I would try a much smaller file and see how much it uses after a full GC to get an idea.

Comment: This phrase doesn't seem to make much sense `The GC is only performed which you need it to.`

Comment: @pedrofurla *which* is probably a typo; it should be really **when**. What is meant by this is that, GC will only run when there is pressure for it to run. In jdk-8 there's a flag that should be on by default `PrintGCCause` that will show you what actually triggered the GC

Comment: What do you mean by 8 objects? Is it about the size of char array resides in the String object? Another question is; how can I merge that big text files with this memory usage? I have 3 pieces of 3gb text files which contains co-occurred words and their frequencies and I need to merge them. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @katilsperm if you are merging a frequency summary, you shouldn't have a memory problem. I suspect the issues is still that you are actually using far less memory than you think as it's only the size after a full GC which matters and your JVM has done one yet.